# merge_vars not working while using Mandrill API in Node

Tags: node.js, mandrill

Here is my code:

```
export class EmailGateway {
    constructor(mandrill, person) {
        this.person = person;
        this.to = [{
            "email": this.person.email,
            "name": `${this.person.first} ${this.person.last}`,
            "type": "to"
        }];
        this.mandrill = mandrill;
    }

    sendTemplateMessage(templateName, mergeVars) {
        return new Bluebird((resolve, reject) => {
            this.mandrill.messages.sendTemplate({
                "template_name": templateName,
                "template_content": [],
                "async": true,
                "message": {
                    "to": this.to,
                    "global_merge_vars": mergeVars,
                    "merge": true
                }
            }, resolve, reject);
        });
    }
}

    let person = config.person.person;
    let e = new EmailGateway(client, person);
    let mergeVars = [
        {
            "name": "first_name",
            "content": person.first
        },
        {
            "name": "cs_date",
            "content": config.callsheet.related('day').get('date')
        },
        {
            "name": "calltime",
            "content": person.callTime
        },
        {
            "name": "parking_location",
            "content": config.callsheet.related('misc').related('location').fullLocation()
        },
        {
            "name": "notes",
            "content": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "dept_notes",
            "content": config.note
        },
        {
            "name": "cs_confirmlink",
            "content": "http://www.setheroapp.com/"
        },
        {
            "name": "cs_link",
            "content": "http://www.setheroapp.com/"
        }
    ];

    e.sendTemplateMessage('Callsheet Email', mergeVars).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return next(null, res);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Every single time a send an email with the above code, I receive the email, but none of the merge vars are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my merge vars in Mandrill from MailChimp tags to Handlebar Tags and everything works now